# How to add X/Y data from Excel file (saved as CSV) on shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, shapefile, data, csv, xy

I need to add my X/Y coordinate data as points from my Excel I need help with adding points (using X/Y coordinates). Can anyone help?

```py
import arcpy   
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/myFolder"
env.overwriteOutput = True
out_path = "C:/myFolder"

out_name = "X_Y_Points.shp"
geometry_type = "MULTIPOINT"
has_m = "DISABLED"
has_z = "DISABLED"
```

Comment: You should look into Insert cursors from the [data access module](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000000t000000), especially the `SHAPE@XY` token.

Comment: Also, make sure that your field names confirm to what ArcGIS expects. See 'Field naming guidelines' here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000000t000000

Answer (score 0):

For the Arcpy way, you're very close! You just need to start an insert cursor, open your CSV file, loop through the rows in your csv, and add your points into your shapefile. Here's some untested code to merge into yours, just to get you started:

```
point_file = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, geometry_type, "", has_m, has_z, sr)
spreadsheet = "C:/my_folder/X-Y.csv"
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(point_file, ["SHAPE@XY", "OTHER_FIELDS", "STRONGBAD"])    
f = open(spreadsheet, 'r')
for line in f:
     # split CSV based on your schema here #
     newpoint = (line.X, line.Y)
     cursor.insertRow(newpoint, line.other_fields, line.emails)
```

Since you're on ArcGIS 10.1, there's also the non-Arcpy way:

1. Set your Data Frame to the appropriate CRS
2. Go to `File -> Add Data -> Add XY Data...`
3. Profit!

You may need to tell ArcMap where your X/Y columns are, if it isn't obvious.

Comment: Doh! I misspelled `InsertCursor` - Edited my answer.

Comment: Also, you will need to modify the comment in my code `# split CSV based on your schema here #` - I don't know what your CSV looks like, so you'll need to split `line` by comma and assign the appropriate values in the following two lines.